# Latency in row-level geo partitioning in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Questions about row-level geolocation partition. Say I have two partitions in USA and one in Singapore. If a user who daily access via USA flys to Singapore.  My question is will the user's reads and writes be slower because most of the data lives in USA? At the same time if the user flies back to USA and is doing read and update to rows that were created in Singapore, will it be slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that row-level geo partition means that you decide on a per-row basis, where it will be located.
In this case, if you want the rows to reside in USA, it will involve multi-region latency to query them from Singapore.

> At the same time if the user flies back to USA and is doing read and
> update to rows that were created in Singapore, will it be slower?

Assuming the rows were being inserted in USA all along, it will be fast, since it's in the same continent.